# ImproperlyConfigured at /app/category/Python/

Tags: python, django

I wanna make a page which shows POST's models' contents is shown each category.For example, when I put Python link in  in detail.html,only POST's models' contents with Python's category is shown in category.html.When I put Python link in category.html,I got an error,ImproperlyConfigured at /app/category/Python/ CategoryView is missing a QuerySet. Define CategoryView.model, CategoryView.queryset, or override CategoryView.get_queryset(). I wrote codes in views.py

```
def top(request):
        content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
        category_content = Category.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
        page = _get_page(blog_content, request.GET.get('page'))

        return render(request, 'top.html',{'content':content,'category_content':category_content,"page":page})

   class CategoryView(BaseListView):
     template_name = 'category.html'

     def get_queryset(self):
        category_name = self.kwargs['category']
        self.category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(category=self.category)
        return queryset

     def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['category'] = self.category
        return context
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    path('category/<str:category>/',views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
]
```

in models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class POST(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

in top.html

```
<div class="list-group">
            <a href="#">
              Category
            </a>
                   <div>
                         {% for category in category_content %}
                            <a href="{% url 'category' category.name %}">
                            {{ category.name }}
                            </a>
                         {% endfor %}
                   </div>
</div>
```

in category.html

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Category</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
                     {% for content in queryset %}
                        <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
                        <img src="content.image.url" />
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a>
                     {% endfor %}
    </div>

          <div>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
              Category
            </a>
                   <div>
                         {% for category in category_content %}
                            <a class="list-group-item justify-content-between" href="{% url 'category' category.name %}">
                            {{ category.name }}
                            </a>
                         {% endfor %}
                   </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I really cannot understand why ImproperlyConfigured which means settings.py is wrong.When I changed BaseListView into ListView,same error happens.I wrote get_queryset in CategoryView's class so I cannot understand codes needs QuerySet. How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that you're calling `super().get_queryset()`, which [expects your class to define a `queryset` or a `model`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d2afa5eb2308e672b6313876856e32e2561b90f3/django/views/generic/list.py#L32). Adding `model = Category` will fix that error.

It looks like you're returning a queryset with just one entry, though. If you only want to get the one category, it would be simpler to use a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView):

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import Category  # or wherever it is


class CategoryView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category.html'

    def get_object(self):
        category_name = self.kwargs['category']
        return Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
```

Note that your template would need to be updated to reference `category` or `object` instead of looping through the queryset.